# App / protocol to tune into live audio and video based on schedule or subscription

Tags: video, audio, media-player, podcasts, streaming

Many of us have embraced the podcasting revolution enabled by rss feeds and podcatchers.

Alot of sites now broadcast live streams of what is eventually edited into a podcast.  In most cases listening to the live stream gets you the info several days sooner then the podcast.

So I was wondering if anybody knows of a notification protocol / app that allows me to auto tune into certain streams when they go live, or based on a schedule.  I imagine twitter could be used for the notification but It'd be better not to be tied to a proprietary service.

Example podcasts / live streams

- [noagenda.squarespace.com](http://noagenda.squarespace.com)
- [jupiterbroadcasting.com](http://jupiterbroadcasting.com)
- [twit.tv](http://twit.tv)

Comment: I used to have a Perl wrapper for `mplayer` that switched streams according to a scheduling file; it was timezone aware so I could specify times in the broadcaster's local time and it would adapt to DST changes in either time zone.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used it before, but it looks like [Hidownload 7](http://www.hidownload.com/) can do this. I see a Live Stream Manager that includes a scheduler. Give it a look?